# Live migrate problem Linux KVM VNC port number

Tags: virtualization, qemu, kvm, vnc, libvirt

An error occurs when trying to move a virtual server that uses 5903 as the VNC port by the live migration method

```
internal error: Failed to reserve port 5903
```

The 5903 port is also used on the opposite server. I'm looking for a method to change the VNC port on the running virtual server.

Is there a method you know? I need to take action without shutting down the virtual server.